# How to show a loading icon/bar when okhttp is fetching data from the api in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, okhttp

I want to show a loading icon/bar on my Android app interface when the okhttp client is fetching a response from the API. For now it is just a blank screen before data loads, however I want to show a loading icon before the data loads fully. Below is the code for my okhttp function. Which part pf the code do I exactly add in a loading bar/icon and how can i do that?

```
private void doGetRequest(String[] time_duration) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(10,TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        client = builder.build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {


                    try {

                       
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                        JSONArray jarray = Jobject.getJSONArray("Flights");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                            
                         
                            }

                        }


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    DeparturesActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            try {


                                for (int i = 0; i < departure_flights.size(); i++) {

                                    String departure_date = departure_flights.get(i).getString("FldaDT");
                                    String flight_number = departure_flights.get(i).getString("Flno");
              

                                   }

                                    flightItems.add(new FlightItem(strDate, flight_number));

                                }
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }


        });
```

Comment: right before `client.newCall(request).enqueue` then hide it onFailure/onResponse is where you'd use it, build something you want to show, lots of resources available for that

Comment: I want a loader on the activity itself and not as a dialog, so is that possible?

Comment: yes, just add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a progressbar in the xml layout and set its visiblity to gone , and at line before you start the call to the api set its visiblity to visible like :

```
progressBar.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
```

And finally when the api call end set its visiblity on `onResponse()` or `onFailure()` to gone again like :

```
progressBar.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```